# How to use notifyDataSetChanged on CustomAdapter?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, notifydatasetchanged

in my android application i have a ExpandableListView and BaseExpandableListAdapter the BaseExpandableListAdapter is in a separate class. In the list i have a delete button inside the child row of the list , The button remove the current row but the list are stay like before and not show it in real time. I get the data to the adapter via my DbHandler into a HashMap . I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged() but no result else i running onCreate again.
How can i solve that?

Comment: Please post the code where button click removes current row.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged from the UI thread?

Comment: If you mean from "MainActivity"? so yes

Comment: and the adapter from another class

Comment: This will work but not sure this is the best way to do, after you delete the row update your hashmap and call setadapter again with the updated values, and after that call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I know but the delete method is in the adapter class and i set the adapter in the the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have initialized your ExpandableListView with two ArrayLists: the first one holds Groups, and the second one - children for that groups. It will look like:

```
private ArrayList<E> mListGroups;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> mGroupsItems;
```

Below is an example on inflating custom layout for child elements with only one TextView in it.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_drawer, null);
        holder = new ItemViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else holder = (ItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    holder.tv.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getName());
    holder.tv.setClickable(true);
    holder.tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mGroupsItems.get(groupPosition).remove(childPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

In order to remove clicked element, you set an OnClickListener on that View and remove element from the list. In your implementation you'll set OnClickListener on an ImageView. That's it.

Ah, one more thing. The above implementation updates only displayed list. The list will remain unchanged in your Activity. So, if you rotate the screen, for example, all removed items will appear again. I'd also implemented an interface and passed updated list back to my Activity from Adapter in a callback.

Comment: thank's but to update via MainActivity i know how to do. my question was how to update in real time on the adapter class beacuse my button is inside the list

Comment: You have any idea please?

Comment: @Matt edited my incorrect answer. Please take a look

Comment: I'm using  hashMap<ArrayList<Model> ,ArrayList<Model>> ; you question not working for me the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged` tells the  ListView` to rebuild all it's item due to changes to the underlaying data.

So basically, what you normally do is:

- Find ListView from Layout
- Create instance of adapter
- Connect ListView and adapter
- Set some data in the adapter
- Call notifyDataSetChanged() to tell the ListView to build it's items (by calling the Adapter's `getCount()`, `getView()` and so on.

When the underlaying data is changed later on (as in your case via Delete button), you remove that item from the data in the adapter, but the listview wouldn't know about it until you notify the ListView about the changed data via a call to `notifyDataSetChangedd()`.

Comment: I know how to build a listView with adapter. look at my question i just want to refreshing the list after i deleted row via the button in the rows

Comment: If you actually remove an item from the data of the Adapter, notifyDataSetChanged will make the removed item go away from the list. If it is not gone, there's something wrong with how you remove the data. It would help if you could post the relevant code.